# Is there any patches for tegra-minimal-initramfs.bb to prevent this error?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, nvidia-jetson

I was trying to build core-image-minimal for Jetson TX2 following the instructions from this link
https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Yocto_Support_for_NVIDIA_Jetson_Platforms-Old .
My build configuration is

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "jetson-tx2"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 armv8a crc"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta-tegra           = "dunfell-l4t-r32.4.3:3b4df1ac05e9f96e0363630c036f5445800af435"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:6e89d668246fb37b2217aae7ae57390e793696d8"
```

But I got this error related to **tegra-minimal-initramfs** recipe.

```
WARNING: tegra-minimal-initramfs-1.0-r0 do_image_complete: KeyError in .
ERROR: tegra-minimal-initramfs-1.0-r0 do_image_complete: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:sstate_report_unihash(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/poky-dunfell/meta/classes/sstate.bbclass', lineno: 844, function: sstate_report_unihash
     0840:    report_unihash = getattr(bb.parse.siggen, 'report_unihash', None)
     0841:
     0842:    if report_unihash:
     0843:        ss = sstate_state_fromvars(d)
 *** 0844:        report_unihash(os.getcwd(), ss['task'], d)
     0845:}
     0846:
     0847:#
     0848:# Shell function to decompress and prepare a package for installation
File: '/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/poky-dunfell/bitbake/lib/bb/siggen.py', lineno: 555, function: report_unihash
     0551:
     0552:            if "." in self.method:
     0553:                (module, method) = self.method.rsplit('.', 1)
     0554:                locs['method'] = getattr(importlib.import_module(module), method)
 *** 0555:                outhash = bb.utils.better_eval('method(path, sigfile, task, d)', locs)
     0556:            else:
     0557:                outhash = bb.utils.better_eval(self.method + '(path, sigfile, task, d)', locs)
     0558:
     0559:            try:
File: '/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/poky-dunfell/bitbake/lib/bb/utils.py', lineno: 420, function: better_eval
     0416:    if extraglobals:
     0417:        ctx = copy.copy(ctx)
     0418:        for g in extraglobals:
     0419:            ctx[g] = extraglobals[g]
 *** 0420:    return eval(source, ctx, locals)
     0421:
     0422:@contextmanager
     0423:def fileslocked(files):
     0424:    """Context manager for locking and unlocking file locks."""
File: '<string>', lineno: 1, function: <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File: '/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/poky-dunfell/meta/lib/oe/sstatesig.py', lineno: 593, function: OEOuthashBasic
     0589:
     0590:                update_hash("\n")
     0591:
     0592:            # Process this directory and all its child files
 *** 0593:            process(root)
     0594:            for f in files:
     0595:                if f == 'fixmepath':
     0596:                    continue
     0597:                process(os.path.join(root, f))
File: '/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/poky-dunfell/meta/lib/oe/sstatesig.py', lineno: 553, function: process
     0549:                    add_perm(stat.S_IXOTH, 'x')
     0550:
     0551:                if include_owners:
     0552:                    try:
 *** 0553:                        update_hash(" %10s" % pwd.getpwuid(s.st_uid).pw_name)
     0554:                        update_hash(" %10s" % grp.getgrgid(s.st_gid).gr_name)
     0555:                    except KeyError:
     0556:                        bb.warn("KeyError in %s" % path)
     0557:                        raise
Exception: KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/jetson_tx2-poky-linux/tegra-minimal-initramfs/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image_complete.23961
ERROR: Task (/home/pc_1175/yocto-tegra/meta-tegra/recipes-core/images/tegra-minimal-initramfs.bb:do_image_complete) failed with exit code '1'
```

The problem is that I have built the same image before with the same packages and I didn't get this error.
When I added **TEGRA_INITRAMFS_INITRD = "0"** to **local.conf** file I didn't get this error but I'm wondering if it can affect my system.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**
Just clean image recipe working directory with `bitbake -c cleansstate tegra-minimal-initramfs` and also `bitbake -c cleansstate core-image-minimal` just in case. Than build should work, but it may be not reproducible. That is, maybe you'll have to call this two `cleansstate` commands before building images (`tegra-minimal-initramfs` and `core-image-minimal`) every time.

I got same issue when migrated my project (not connected with Tegra) to Yocto 3.2. The issue was with [pseudo](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.5/overview-manual/overview-manual-concepts.html#fakeroot-and-pseudo) - it is a fakeroot-tool, that is used in Yocto for generating rootfs with right files permissions (you run `bitbake` as an ordinary user, not root, but get rootfs with all files belonging to root). Here is [bug](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14193) i've posted with my patch.

But you are using Yocto 3.1.5 as i see, so your issue is different. The core reason is that during some package build (the one that was **excluded** by `TEGRA_INITRAMFS_INITRD = "0"`) `pseudo` remembered, that some file should belong to user `1000`, but during building `tegra-minimal-initramfs` (generation of initramfs) user `1000` was not found in initramfs itself... because there are only root and some basic Linux users.

To your question, may anything break if you leave `TEGRA_INITRAMFS_INITRD = "0"`. Likely **yes**. [Here](https://github.com/OE4T/meta-tegra/blob/76b657555d5b33cdfda6cd56c2db2622f123e650/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-tegra-bootimg.inc) is where this variable is applied. It is used during U-Boot build and looks like it turns off initramfs usage at all. So with `TEGRA_INITRAMFS_INITRD = "0"` your final image wouldn't include initramfs file. If the device has some fallback mechanism to boot without initramfs, seems you are ok. If not - try `cleansstate`.